# Changing global variable javascript

Tags: javascript

I want to use global variable number = 2, but when in input form something is put I want to change value of global variable because I'm going to use it in another function so at the beginning I want number = 2 but when other value is put in input form I want number to take that value.

```
<form onsubmit="return timed('commands')">
    <input type="number" name="a" id="commands"><br>
</form>
```

```
   var number= 2;
   function timed(id)
   {
       number=getElementById(id).value;
       return false;
   }
```

Comment: What is the problem here? What do you expect to happen? What happens instead?

Comment: For example I put in input form "10" and I want global variable number to change but it's not happening.

Comment: Where and how did you check that?

Comment: I put a value in input I checked number with console.log and it didn't change

Answer (score 0):

You can add the event onchange to handle this:

```html
<form onsubmit="return timed('commands')">
            <input type="number" name="a" id="commands" onchange="changeNumber(this.value)"/><br>
</form>
```

And add the function in the  area:

```html
function changeNumber(value){
            number=value
}
```

Comment: I checked it and it works as before